# Playing audio when a button is pressed

Tags: ios

I've been using the following function to play sounds.

```
- (void) playFile:(NSString *)nameOfFile
{
    NSString *tmpFileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:nameOfFile];
    NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tmpFileName
                                                         ofType:@"mp3"];

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained  CFURLRef)
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);    
}
```

I've noticed that if the button that calls this is pressed again, the sound just plays over the top of the existing playing sound. How can I augment this code to stop sounds playing again and instead 'restart' the playing file? Should I play the sounds using a different API?

Comment: P.S. I appreciate it may be a dumb question :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVAudioPlayer to do that, just allocate it in your init/viewdidload then when the button is pressed do something like:

```
[self.player stop]
self.player.currentTime=0;
[self.player play];
```